# Vectorizing a Physics Simulation?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, physics, jax

I'm trying to simulate some 2-dimensional particles. Each particle is a circle that has an orientation. The orientation is specified by a 2-dimensional unit vector.

In one part of my simulation I'd like to calculate a function of the angle between particle pairs and each particle's orientation. This should be done for each particle pair. Visually, I'd like to calculate a function of $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ (see image link).

I've calculated the pairwise displacement unit-vectors for each particle pair. This is in a numpy array called r of shape (N, N, 2) where N is the total number of particles. I've also calculated the orientation for each particle in cartesian coordinates. This is a numpy array called orientation of shape (N, 2).

I've been able to write the code I need as a double for-loop.

```
output = np.zeros(r.shape)
for i in range(len(r)):
      for j in range(len(r[i])):
        if (i < j):
          theta_i = angle_between(orientation[i], r[i,j])
          theta_j = angle_between(orientation[j], r[i,j])
          output[i][j] = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_i) - np.cos(alpha))))) * (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_j) - np.cos(alpha)))))
```

It takes far to long to run this code though, especially for large systems. Is there a way to vectorize the double for loop so that it runs faster?

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? with like 3 particles or smth

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of me running your code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

N = 3
r_hat = np.random.rand(N, N, 2)
moment_cartesian = np.random.rand(N, 2)
output = np.zeros(r_hat.shape)
output = np.zeros((N, N))
w = 1
alpha = 1
theta_i_ij = np.zeros((N, N))
theta_j_ij = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(len(r_hat)):
      for j in range(len(r_hat[i])):
        if (i < j):
          theta_i = angle_between(moment_cartesian[i], r_hat[i,j])
          theta_j = angle_between(moment_cartesian[j], r_hat[i,j])
          theta_i_ij[i, j] = theta_i
          theta_j_ij[i, j] = theta_j
          output[i][j] = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_i) - np.cos(alpha))))) * (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_j) - np.cos(alpha)))))

print(f'theta_i_ij = \n{theta_i_ij}')
print(f'theta_j_ij = \n{theta_j_ij}')
print(f'output = \n{output}')
```

Output:

```
theta_i_ij = 
[[0.         0.99438035 0.98889055]
 [0.         0.         0.9954101 ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
theta_j_ij = 
[[0.         0.99873953 0.99891568]
 [0.         0.         0.90135909]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
output = 
[[0.         0.25072287 0.25127888]
 [0.         0.         0.26052633]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Here's an example of a vectorisation of the code:

```
innerp    = np.einsum('jk,ijk->ij', moment_cartesian, r_hat)
norm      = np.linalg.norm(moment_cartesian, axis = -1)[None, :]*np.linalg.norm(r_hat, axis = -1)
theta_j_v = innerp/norm

innerp    = np.einsum('ik,ijk->ij', moment_cartesian, r_hat)
norm      = np.linalg.norm(moment_cartesian, axis = -1)[:, None]*np.linalg.norm(r_hat, axis = -1)
theta_i_v = innerp/norm

output_v = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_i_v) - np.cos(alpha))))) * (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_j_v) - np.cos(alpha)))))


print(f'theta_i_v = \n{theta_i_v}')
print(f'theta_j_v = \n{theta_j_v}')
print(f'output_v = \n{output_v}')
```

Output:

```
theta_i_v = 
[[0.99717384 0.99438035 0.98889055]
 [0.9090371  0.95351666 0.9954101 ]
 [0.99986414 0.98876437 0.87290329]]
theta_j_v = 
[[0.99717384 0.99873953 0.99891568]
 [0.96281813 0.95351666 0.90135909]
 [0.98397106 0.9796661  0.87290329]]
output_v = 
[[0.25059435 0.25072287 0.25127888]
 [0.26327747 0.25972068 0.26052633]
 [0.2516916  0.25331216 0.27620631]]
```

I must say though, that I did not think of a way to vectorize your code without unnecessarily calculating the lower triangle of the matrix.
You actually don't need to vectorize your code at all.
If you use Numba to compile a function containing your code, it will perform the same operation just as fast if not even more quickly than vectorized solutions.

Here's my Numba example:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def computations(r_hat, moment_cartesian, alpha, w):
    output = np.zeros((N, N))
    for i in range(len(r_hat)):
        for j in range(len(r_hat[i])):
            if (i < j):
                v0 = r_hat[i,j]
                v1 = moment_cartesian[i]
                v2 = moment_cartesian[j]
                theta_i = np.sum(v0*v1)/(np.sum(v0**2)*np.sum(v1**2))**0.5
                theta_j = np.sum(v0*v2)/(np.sum(v0**2)*np.sum(v2**2))**0.5
                output[i][j] = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_i) - np.cos(alpha))))) * (1 / (1 + np.exp(-w*(np.cos(theta_j) - np.cos(alpha)))))
    return output

print(f'output = \n{computations(r_hat, moment_cartesian, alpha, w)}')
```

Output:

```
output = 
[[0.         0.25072287 0.25127888]
 [0.         0.         0.26052633]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you sure your vectorization is correct? When you run my code you get the same answer as when you run your code, however I don't. Running my code yeilds: theta_i_ij = 
[[0.         0.10606531 0.14919839]
 [0.         0.         0.09584795]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
theta_j_ij = 
[[0.         0.05021425 0.04657283]
 [0.         0.         0.44789873]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
output = 
[[0.         0.37469783 0.37392392]
 [0.         0.         0.36056265]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]] instead of what you have.

Comment: @iamsad I can't help you without a Minimal Reproducible Example. And please show the whole code you ran when you got those results.

Comment: I ran exactly what you ran under "Here's an example of me running your code:"

Comment: Could you try running this again and see what you get? When I run what you have under "Here's an example of me running your code:" and "Here's an example of a vectorisation of the code:" I don't get the same result. I'm not sure how you do. If you do get the same result could you please explain briefly the 3 lines of code you use in your vectorization to get the theta_i_v matrix? Thank you for your assistance, I appreciate it.

Comment: @iamsad  I can't help you without a Minimal Reproducible Example. Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post